# Windows Driver programming, Thread function data argument gets corrupted?

Tags: windows, multithreading, timer, driver, wdm

I'm testing this code:

```
int handler(void* data)
{
    KTIMER *Timer = (KTIMER *)data;
    DbgPrint("*** timer1.sys: Inside handler ...\n");
    DbgPrint("handler: Address of data: %p\n", data);
    if (STATUS_SUCCESS == KeWaitForSingleObject(Timer,
                                        Executive, KernelMode , 
                                        TRUE, NULL)){
            DbgPrint("Status_Succes for KeWaitForSingleObject");
    } 
    DbgPrint("Done waiting!!! ...\n");
    KeCancelTimer(Timer);
    return 1;
}

void start_timer()
{
    KTIMER Timer;
    LARGE_INTEGER lTimeOut;
    PKTHREAD *delayedWorkerThread;
    void* data;

    DbgPrint("*** timer1.SYS: ==>start_timer\n");

    KeInitializeTimer(&Timer);
    lTimeOut.QuadPart = 3000;           //Delay
    lTimeOut.QuadPart *= 10000;         // 100ns * 10000 = 1ms
    lTimeOut.QuadPart *= -1;            // exactly waiting time
    KeSetTimer(&Timer, lTimeOut, NULL);


    /*
    if (STATUS_SUCCESS == KeWaitForSingleObject(&Timer,
                                        Executive, KernelMode , 
                                        TRUE, NULL)){
            DbgPrint("Status_Succes for KeWaitForSingleObject");
    } 
    DbgPrint("Call Handler ...\n");
    KeCancelTimer(&Timer);
    */

    data = &Timer;
    DbgPrint("start_timer: Address of Timer: &Timer: %p\n", &Timer);
    DbgPrint("Start_timer: Address of Timer: data: %p\n", data);
    delayedWorkerThread = thread_create(handler, data, "Delayed Worker Thread"); // This function will create a thread using PsCreateSystemThread and will return PTHREAD object
    DbgPrint("timer1.sys: start_timer<==\n");
}
```

Now when I load this driver, my m/c crashes with (IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL_TO) at `KeWaitForSingleObject` that means, I'm trying to access invalid address. But Timer address is same in handler and in start_timer. Without KeWaitForSingleObject its fine. I don't know what is wrong, if anyone can help!

***//////////////////////////////
EDIT 1
//////////////////////////////***

WIthout `KeWaitForSingleObject` i.e.

```
int handler(void* data)
{
    KTIMER *Timer = (KTIMER *)data;
    DbgPrint("*** timer1.sys: Inside handler ...\n");
    DbgPrint("handler: Address of data: %p\n", data);    // Same address
    DbgPrint("handler: Address of Timer: %p\n", TImer);  // Same address

    DbgPrint("Done waiting!!! ...\n");
    KeCancelTimer(Timer);
    return 1;
}
```

Its crashing later .. installing driver successfully and also unloading successfully ... then suddenly blue screen! Windows driver programming isn't child's play! :(

Still same address in both the function .. BTW it works fine whn I write without thread ... (Uncommenting code in start_timer()) But I have to do it with thread ... What I want to do is, calling start_timer() with different delay multiple time, and handler should be called accordingly it should not block other execution hence creating thread.

Comment: `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL_TO` is *not* telling you you're accessing an invalid address... that's called an "access violation"

Comment: The most common cause of this error is an incorrect or corrupted pointer that references an incorrect location in memory. A pointer is a variable used by a program to refer to a block of memory. If the variable has an incorrect value in it, the program tries to access memory that it should not.
I read from here ...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957609.aspx

Comment: It's a subtle point, but by "incorrect" location, they don't mean the address is invalid. They just mean that you're not at the correct IRQL for accessing that memory (possibly because it's paged), so it's only "incorrect" or "invalid" in the sense that you shouldn't be accessing it there -- not that it's already-freed or something.

Comment: oh oh .. that means my TImer data is still there, and I'm calling PAGED_CODE macro in driver unload ... I read somewhere, we should call this macro for every driver routine ... still no idea why? and also didnt get it what you mean by "They just mean that you're not at the correct IRQL for accessing that memory (possibly because it's paged)" .. could you please elaborate ? Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about PAGED_CODE  -- it's an optimization you can always leave off. As long as you use it only where they tell you, it's fine. The rest is kind of hard/long to explain, but [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554368.aspx) might be helpful. (Note that I'm saying the error you got didn't *necessarily* mean the address is invalid -- simply that it's paged memory -- but of course, *if* the address is invalid, then that error can also happen.)

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad .. some what clean about IRQL, but I'm calling all this method in driver_entry only ... that means its passive level ..I can access it ... and abt invalid address, I'm printing before creating thread(start_timer) .. its same as in handler (thread method) so how its just get lost?! .. I simple tried passing some struct data to handler(void*) without thread ... that simply worked fine ... wrong with IRQL level or what?

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, it's strange that it's not giving you STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION instead. I don't know why the message is weird, but Hans's answer seems to be right.

Comment: thanks Mehrdad! I'm waiting for Hans answer then!!! but one more question ... I'm creating a driver and removing .. so before my handler gets called, driver is unloaded .. is there anyway to make driver wait for pending operation before unloading? Thanks again!

Comment: I think you can set `DRIVER_OBJECT`'s `DriverUnload` field to a handler that will get called when your driver is about to be unloaded... does that do what you want?

Comment: oh I have routine that will unload driver as you said ... but the thing is it gets called before my timer expires and do whatever (some routine say timer_expires_handler() will be called after timer expires, after KeWaitForSingleObject) ... but that DriverUnload is unloading my driver before timer_expires_handler() can be called .. I don't want that ... I want my driver to wait for it!

Comment: Ohh... can you make an event to wait on, and when the timer expires, set the event? Then wait on the event when you're unloading. (Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried this -- it might cause race conditions with the timer, I don't know.)

Comment: hey Mehrdad, thanks!... I make it work with KeDelayExecutionThread and thanks Hans too ... he's right for thread data, we have to  allocate memory with ExAllocatePoolWithTag. Thanks both of u! :))